# Bitwise method of generating r for RSA-KEM

Tags: rsa, random-number-generator, key-derivation, padding

It seems that RSA-KEM has a very troublesome method of generating the secret $r$. It seems that the random value needs to be in the range $0 \le r \le {n - 1}$.

Now most cryptographic environments don't have a random number generator that generates those kind of numbers; usually they are just provided with a seeded DRBG that outputs full bytes. Performing all kinds of integer operations on the bytes may lead to leaks of the master key within these kind of environments. Especially the $\bmod$ operation seems to be tricky in this regards.

Is there a known good way of generating $r$ that disposes of the $\bmod$ operation and possible looping?

---

For instance I could think of constructing $r$ as

```
00 | R
```

The `|` operation is of course concatenation.

In this construction $R$ is then an octet string consisting of (pseudo) random bytes. $r$ consists of the value of `00 | R` when used as a big endian unsigned integer. It can be used directly as input to raw "RSA encryption" as implemented by most libraries.

That would provide $\operatorname{len}(R) * 8$ bits of entropy for the KDF. I think that would be $\lfloor (log_2(n) - 1) / 8\rfloor \cdot 8$ bits of entropy when measured against the modulus value $n$.

The scheme would otherwise be unaltered of course; there would be no explicit checks on the value of $r$ during decryption.

Would this suffice as a secure scheme of constructing $r$ instead of performing integer calculations and checks to get to $0 \le r \le {n - 1}$?

Comment: This is half a suggestion/half a question regarding "Is there a known good way of generating m that disposes of the mod operation and possible looping?": I have been using `(data && mask) || floor`, where mask is equal to `(1 << required_bits) - 1` and floor is set to the minimum bound to retrieve a value x: floor <= x <= mask. This appears to provide me with a value in the appropriate range in constant time, but I am not certain of how "clean" it is in terms of bias or if it's helpful to you here (I see you need x < y <z whereas I need x <= y <= z).

Comment: Why do you require $1<m$? I see no issues with $0$ and $1$.

Comment: It should be straightforward to show that reducing the space of the message by 1 bit can't reduce security by more than 1 bit.

Comment: Since a CSPRNG seeded from a low/no entropy seed still produces a random looking sequence, that doesn't seem like a worthwhile protection to me. Also mapping 0 to 2 won't help you in that case, since you can guess it just as easily.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've removed the > 1 requirement from the quesetion, I'll probably edit the Wikipedia article to be more scientific (or at least correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options.  I include modular reduction and rejection sampling because I suspect they are less costly than you worry.

1. What you suggested, roughly: **Pick $r$ uniformly in $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} - 1\}$.**

   If there were an IND-CCA2 or NM-CCA2 adversary with success probability $p$ against RSA-KEM with $r$ uniform in $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n - 1\}$, the success probability of the same adversary can't be more than $2p$ since we're removing less than half the possible space of $r$.  If $2p$ was too high, then $p$ was almost certainly too high already.  If you set the high *byte* to zero, as you suggested, then you remove more of the output space and it's $256p$ instead of just $2p$.

   Theoretical concern: The standard security reduction to the RSA problem[[1]](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf#page=59), which demonstrates how to turn an IND-CCA2 attacker into a procedure to compute $e^{\mathit{th}}$ roots modulo $n$, would no longer apply, because a little under half the space is guaranteed not to be covered.  It's a little hard to imagine that the *general* RSA problem is hard, but becomes easy if you restrict it to this domain; however, the more space you eliminate, the more irrelevant the reduction becomes to justifying the security, so better to set the high *bit* to zero than to set the high *byte* to zero as you suggested.
2. Modular reduction: **Pick $r$ uniformly in $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor + k} - 1\}$ where $k$ is, say, 64, or 256 if you're paranoid or $\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$ if you're really paranoid, and reduce modulo $n$.**

   You don't need a general purpose division routine: You can easily reduce $r$ modulo $n$ in constant time with Barrett reduction using only two multiplications and a subtraction, if you precompute $2^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil}/n$ (with bit-by-bit long division in constant time if $n$ is ever secret), as long as $r < n^2$.

   This doesn't give a uniform distribution, but it's awfully close—much closer than option (1), if for no other reason than that it doesn't completely exclude any of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ like (1) does.  (Exercise for the reader: Quantify the modulo bias in, say, total variation distance—this puts a similar bound on the advantage of an IND-CCA2 or NM-CCA2 adversary *vs.* a true uniform distribution.)
3. Rejection sampling: **Pick $r$ uniformly in $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, 2^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil} - 1\}$, and start over if $r \geq n$.**

   Since $2^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil}/2 < n < 2^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil}$, the number of trials is geometrically distributed with probability $p < 1/2$; the expected number of trials is just over 1 and well below 2.  You will obviously never see more than 128 trials—for a 4096-bit RSA modulus, you need to generate much less than 4096 KB of data.

   This guarantees a uniform distribution for $r$ in $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n - 1\}$.

Comment: So 1. would be my idea, 2. would be modular reduction and 3. would be rejection sampling I assume? Well, I know, but it's not in the text.